# gcc can't find the linking lldap libraries even with -Llibrary-path specified, why?

Tags: gcc, linker-errors

I have a smal testing program to test ldap. I tried to compile it on Ubuntu 19.04. I have the source file called myldaptest.c, I ran:
1.gcc -c myldaptest.c
2.gcc -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lldap -llber -o myldaptest myldaptest.o

then the it complains:
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.o: in function `main':
ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x236): undefined reference to`ldap_url_parse'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x30b): undefined reference to `ldap_initialize'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x33a): undefined reference to`ldap_set_option'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x374): undefined reference to `ldap_set_option'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x3a3): undefined reference to`ldap_set_option'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x3ea): undefined reference to `ldap_set_option'
/usr/bin/ld: ldapsearch-sync.c:(.text.startup+0x422): undefined reference to`ldap_set_option'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

who can tell me why?

Comment: Try moving -L and -l switches at the end "gcc -o myldaptest myldaptest.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lldap -llber"

Comment: Hi lcarus3, it magically worked, I don't understand why the order matters! Thank you very much, it stopped me for a few hours!

Comment: Unix linkers are single pass linker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854309/why-do-i-have-to-pass-libraries-in-the-end-of-linker-line